# Getting 'LazyStrategy' object instead of integer in hypothesis when using flatmap

Tags: python, python-3.x, testing, automated-tests, python-hypothesis

Working with the python testing framework `hypothesis`, I would like to achieve a rather complex composition of testing strategies: 1. I would like to test against create strings `s` which consist of a unique character set. 2. Each of these examples I want to run through a function `func(s: str, n: int) -> Tuple[str, int]` which takes a string `s` and an integer `n` as a parameters. Here, I want to make the integer be populated by hypothesis as well, but the maximum value of `n` should be `len(s)`, the length of `s`. I've tried to use `flatmap`, but do not understand it sufficiently yet to get it to work. Here is the minimal example of what I've tried:

```py
from typing import Tuple

from hypothesis import given
from hypothesis.strategies import text, integers


def func(s: str, n: int) -> Tuple[str, int]:
    for i in range(n):
        pass  # I do something here on s, which is not relevant to the question

    return (s, n)

# 1. Create the strategy for unique character strings:
unique_char_str = text().map(lambda s: "".join(set(s)))

#2. Create the complex strategy with flatmap:
confined_tuple_str_int = unique_char_str.flatmap(
    lambda s: func(s, integers(min_value=0, max_value=len(s)))
)
```

When I try to use this new strategy,

```py
@given(tup=confined_tuple_str_int)
def test_foo(tup):
    pass
```

I get a FAILED test, claiming

> test_foo - TypeError: 'LazyStrategy' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

In the line `for i in range(n):`, in `func`, `n` is not an integer, but a `LazyStrategy` object.

That tells me, I have some misconception of how `flatmap` works, but I cannot figure it out on my own.

What do I need to do, to define my testing strategy properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `flatmap`, you cannot combine two dependent strategies - this can be done using the `composite` decorator instead:

```py
@composite
def confined_tuple_str_int(draw, elements=text()):
    s = draw(lists(characters(), unique=True).map("".join))
    i = draw(integers(min_value=0, max_value=len(s)))
    return func(s, i)


@given(confined_tuple_str_int())
def test_foo(tup):
    print(tup)
```

The `draw` argument allows you to get the drawn value of a strategy (e.g. an example) - in this case a unique string - and use it to create a strategy dependent on that value - in this case an integer strategy dependent on the string length. After also drawing an example from that strategy, the composite decorator creates a new strategy from these example values and returns it.

*Disclaimer*: I'm new to `hypothesis`, so my terminology may be a bit off.

*Edit*: Updated to make sure that the order of examples is preserved, as suggested by Zac Hatfield-Dodds in the comments.

Comment: Careful!  `"".join(set(s))` might have a nondeterministic order, and thus break replay of failing examples.  I'd suggest using `s=st.lists(st.characters(), unique=True).map("".join)` to generate unique strings, and `assert len(s) == len(set(s))` as a check for user-supplied strategies.

Comment: And as a trick, the flatmap version: `s.map(lambda s: st.tuples(st.just(s), st.integers(0, len(s)).flatmap(lambda x: x)`.  I don't recommend doing this, as composite is usually a lot clearer, but combining `.map`+`.flatmap` can do anything if you don't care for readability!

Comment: Thanks for that! I didn't think about that part (the set), just took it from the original code, but that makes sense! I will update the answer accordingly.